# Fix for "find selected text" in workspace xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

If I double click a word in xcode and then use the "find selected text in workspace" it does not work.  When I go to the edit->find->find in selected text in workspace, it is not enabled.

Once I select more then the word itself, it will be able to search, has anyone got selecting just one word to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me (Xcode 4.4.1).

Comment: Are you sure?? I mean if you double click a word, and use this feature, you will go right to finding the word in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works now after I exited Xcode and restarted.  I also did a delete all derived data with in xcode's organizer.